# Which -ghc-options should I use when using Haskell Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm confused about where I should be putting GHC compile options in Haskell Stack projects. From a review of the documentation, I think I need to use `ghc-options`, but *which one*? There are two:

- [Stack's `ghc-options`](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#ghc-options)
- [Cabal's `ghc-options`](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program) (which it seems people just kind of use, but there's no actual documentation describing what it is ...)

I thought specifying an option for the compiler would be straightforward, but this is mystifying me. What is the preferred/accepted/de-facto/? way to specify GHC options when using Stack to build a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be interested in hearing something more official from the stack folks, but we use cabal and stack on our project, and the answer for us is just one of scope....

We have many subprojects, each with its own .cabal file.  We have one stack file that gives info on how to build the whole project.  Anything that pertains to the whole project (perhaps `-O2`, or whatever) goes in the stack file.

Anything that pertains to just one project (perhaps a stray `-fno-warn-unused-do-bind`) would go in the individual .cabal file.

Sometimes we do have both an individual stack.yaml for a project also, and although we could put the flags in that, it is better to put it in the .cabal file, because that gets used by the overall stack.yaml.